# Website not displaying correctly in Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, safari, rendering, fullpage.js

I'm a complete newbie here. I have been trying to learn to code a site with HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT. 
I am using brackets to code the site. The site I am practicing with renders properly with all css and javascript. 
However when I open the .html file into safari or firefox it does not display correctly. I think it is probably a css issue as the html elements are all there.

I have other sites that I have made before that don't have this issue and I can not see where I have gone wrong.

jsfiddle.net/fs4g55m2/1 I'm using fullpage.js as well. If you notice the navbar works perfectly well. It seems to be the css after it that is corrupted (once you get to the body tag).

Comment: try to reduce the problem to the smallest example you can and then post it here.  sometimes this reduction task will help you find the issue.

Comment: I took out the link to my css and chrome displayed my site the same as safari and firefox. Safari and firefox must be linking to the css because they    are rendering the css up to a certain point. I have linked to my css code here: http://jsfiddle.net/fs4g55m2/ . The code appears to work up until the body tag on safari and firefox.
Maybe you can identify something i can't. (please forgive the shoddy coding)

Comment: provide the html also

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fs4g55m2/1/

I'm using fullpage.js as well.
If you notice the navbar works perfectly well. It seems to be the css after it that is corrupted (once you get to the body tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think it is CSS (and you are linking to external CSS file) try look into the network tabs in your browser's developer console to see if it is properly linked. Check to see if requested css file throw back 404 status (not found) - usually highlighted in red.

In chrome or Firefox (not sure in safari) right click on your web page and click inspect element - then choose network tab.

Hope that helps

Comment: debugging flagged a lot of errors in my code =] it seems chrome is a lot more forgiving than the other browsers. thank you

Comment: True, I used to run into those kind of problems too. Happy coding!